# GridBagLayout showing nothing in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I have a JFrame which uses GridBagLayout. 
I also add to the JFrame objects which extends JPanel. The Panels are shown when I use GridLayout(1,2) , but the reason why I want GridBagLayout is because one of the Panel needs to occupy more space than the other.

```
public class BoardFrame extends JFrame
{ 
    private GridBagLayout gridLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    private GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    public BoardFrame()
    {

        super("Quoridor");
        setLayout(gridLayout);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#c6bf84"));


        BoardPanel aBoardPanel = new BoardPanel(getHeight() , getWidth());
        aBoardPanel.addMouseListener(aBoardPanel);
        aBoardPanel.addMouseMotionListener(aBoardPanel );
        TotalWallPanel wallPanel = new TotalWallPanel(aBoardPanel.getPlayers());
        aBoardPanel.setwallPanelReference(wallPanel);
        addComponent(aBoardPanel, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        addComponent(wallPanel, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1366, 768);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);




    }

    public void addComponent(Component component, int row , int col , int width , int height)
    {
        constraints.gridx = col;
        constraints.gridy = row;
        constraints.gridwidth = width;
        constraints.gridheight = height;
        gridLayout.setConstraints(component, constraints);
        this.add(component);
    }
}
```

This code shows me just an empty frame. I dont understand if the problem stands at the way I have used GridBagLayout , or at the inner layouts of the corresponding panels. Both panels has the layouts set to null cause I work with absolute coordinates to paint in those panels.

Comment: Beware `BoardPanel aBoardPanel = new BoardPanel(getHeight() , getWidth());` would the same as `BoardPanel aBoardPanel = new BoardPanel(0, 0);`

Comment: I had the setSize method of the frame before I call the constructor of the BoardPanel. I sent it in the end just to see if anything changes

Comment: `setResizable` can affect the frame size, so best to call it before `pack` - since the result of your problem is related to what the components you're adding to the view, you will need to include them before anyone can possible help you with any definate solution

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue or not, but using `setConstraints` before adding the component looks suspicious to me, I'd just rely on `add(component, constraints)`, mostly because I know that works :P

Comment: Well that was how the book used the GridBagLayout that why I wrote it. I tried your suggestion , but nothing changed , still the frame is empty.

Comment: So, unless you can provide a working example of your code, showing it not work, that's about the extend of the support we can provide you, everything else is guess work

Comment: What part of code should I show ? The Panels constructors maybe ?
The reason why I didnt involve the code of those two was to not overload the post.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *"Both panels has the layouts set to null cause I work with absolute coordinates to paint in those panels."* Post an MCVE as advised by @MadProgrammer, but just thought I'd point out that sounds very suspicious. When custom painting, the layout is irrelevant (so there's no need to set it `null`). Any other time, a container should have a layout, even if it is one you devised explicitly for that container. The JVM uses hints provided via the layout manager to determine an appropriate size for the container. When custom painting, we need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return ..

Comment: .. a sensible value for the custom painted component.